# Why is it that when I move a value into ax, and use div it won't work in TASM?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm

I am a beginner in assembly and I wanted to make a function to get an integer from the user which is getint. I also wanted to make a function to print an integer which is printint. I did many tests and I found that once I use getint and try to use printint I will send the integer to printint via the stack and then in printint I pop it into ax, but then when I use div with ax it doesn't work. For example say the number in ax is 22 and then I do cmp dl, 2 je exit after using div(je exit would be on the next line it won't work). Can someone tell me what to do to fix this? I would have put all my code but I know that this is the problem. I also pointed out the div statement I was talking about it is towards the end.

```
main:   call getint
    push dx ;the return value for getint is in dx
    call printInt
    jmp done3


getint: pop si ;put the return address in si
    xor bx, bx ; make bx zero
    call getche ;get the first digit
cmp dl, 13 ;if enter was not pressed then continue
je done 
sub dx, 48 ;subtract 48 becuase the number is in ascii
mov bx, dx ;move the number into bx

loop1:
    call getche ;get the next digit 
    cmp dl, 0Dh ;check to see if enter was pressed
    je done
    sub dx, 48 ;subtract 48 in because the number is in ascii
    mov cx, dx ; move the value from getche into cx
    mov ax, 10 
    mul bx ;multiply the origional value of bx by 10
    mov bx, ax ; move the product into bx
    add bx, cx ;move 
    jmp loop1

done:   mov dx, bx ;put the return value in dx
     jmp si ;jump back to the address the function was called from

printInt:
pop si; put the address in si
pop ax ;put the number sent into ax, the correct number does actually get stored into ax but for some reason the division does not work correctly 
cmp al, 0 ;check if the number to print is 0
je itszerofirst ;just a label it will jump to if the condition is true
mov di, 1 ;di will be our counter
mov dx, 0
mov cx, 10 ;this is the division I was talking about where it doesn't work
div cx       ; Divides ax by 10. DX = remainder and AX = other digits 
add dx, 48
push dx
```

Comment: Doesn't work how?  This isn't a [mcve].  Does it crash from falling off the end of `printInt` because there's no `ret`?  Use a debugger to single-step and look at registers.  You are correctly zeroing `dx` before using `div`, so the problem is the surrounding code.

Comment: And BTW, don't forget that `call` pushes a return address.  You should normally access args on the stack by setting up a stack frame and using `mov ax, [bp+4]` or whatever, not `pop`.  Although I guess you *could* for code-size `pop dx` / `pop ax` / `push dx` / `push dx` to load `ax` and leave SP unmodified, and replace the return address onto the stack.  Or much better, just pass the arg in `ax` or whatever other register, instead of the stack!  You get to make up your own calling convention in asm, especially 16-bit.